# How can we filter already in the webserver which clients should be called when SQL broker is triggered?

Tags: sql-server, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

We are trying to understand how we should setup our SQL tables with SQL Broker and Signalr.

Background:
We have a website displaying "people and their statuses" and "signed in users relevant activities".
We want to keep this information updated on change in the SQL database, i.e. if a user changes status.

Currently our data tables can contain multiple companies. I.e., Company 1, Company 2...
When table and company 1 becomes updated with "changes" we only want to alert every client connected to company 1.

Currently our understanding is that SQL broker does not know what got updated, it just informs web server "hey something changed here, let every client connected to THIS TABLE" (or group?) know about it so they can refresh...

If we understand this correctly, we would probably need to create one table for each "group" or company in this case. Right?

OR, is there a way to have the webserver figure out WHO is affected by the table-change, and only let those people know about it?

Picture for possibly some understanding :)
[Sketch 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zaHK.png)

Tried to read up on signalr hubs and filters, do not quite understand how it should work with SQL broker.

Comment: I think it depends on the technology you use for change notifications. SQL Broker doesn't know anything about your data, it just delivers some messages. If you use SQL Query Notifications, then you usually only get to know that something has changed in the query that you are polling. If you use SQL Table notifications, then you are usually able to get details about rows that are changed. I don't know which methology SignalR uses though